# Instantiating Realm model class crashes with missing key error

Tags: swift, realm

When trying to instantiate my `RealmDouble` model I get the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Invalid value '0' to initialize object of type 'RealmDouble': missing
>   key 'double_value'

```
class RealmDouble: Object {
    dynamic var double_value: Double = 0.00
}

RealmDouble(value: 0.0)
```

I have tried deleting the app from the simulator, as well as deleting the Realm file. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you please share the code you're using to instantiate the `RealmDouble` instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd see this exception if you're passing a `Double` in a place where Realm expects to see either a dictionary from property names to values or an array of values, such as [`Realm.create(_:value:update)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm6createuRxCS_6ObjectrFTMx5valueP_6updateSb_x). For instance, you'll see an error like this from the following code:

```
realm.create(RealmDouble.self, value: 0.0)
```

You should instead do:

```
realm.create(RealmDouble.self, value: [0.0])
```

Comment: I was just creating an instance of the RealmDouble(value: 5.5)

Comment: It appears RealmDouble(value: [5.5]) is working correctly.. I don't understand why the [] are needed since I didn't require an array or list type for the model

Comment: The value passed as the `value` parameter is used to populate _all_ properties of the class in question. Passing a single value cannot work in the general case because classes can have more than one persisted property.

Answer (score 0):

From the future if it helps anyone:

Same error was thrown when I accidentally passed the wrong Type on the first parameter of the method `realm.create(type: T.Type, value:_, update:_)`
So make sure type is the correct and set to accept the values you are passing.